# Build names for variables/columns of a R data.frame

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with columns named like this

```
> names(df)
[1] "v1_1_a" "v1_1_b" "v1_2_a"
```

This is just an example of the nameing scheme. There are more columns with that naming scheme. I want to build the column names (of still **existing** columns) and do operations on them like this:

```
# pseudo code! python and R mixed
for minor in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    for letter in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']:
        col = 'v1_{}_{}'.format(minor, letter)
        df[col] <- df[col] * 10
```

Can I *build* variable names like that?

Tried for example: `df[cat("v1_1_", "b", sep="")]`

Comment: I think you want `df[paste0("v_1_", "b")]` not `cat`.

Comment: Are the columns assumed to exist, or do you want to create new columns and add values in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note* this is certainly not the best way to loop through a dataframe as mentioned in the comments below.

You can just paste the variables together and call the columns directly.
Your pseudo code in R:

```
for(minor in c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
     for(letter in c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
         df[,paste0('v1_',minor,'_',letter)] <- df[,paste0('v1_',minor,'_',letter)] *10
```

This doesn't work with your data frame because you don't have all the combinations.  If you're unsure if the combination exists you can check for it before doing the calculations.

```
for(minor in c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
     for(letter in c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
         if(paste0('v1_',minor,'_',letter) %in% colnames(df))
             df[,paste0('v1_',minor,'_',letter)] <- df[,paste0('v1_',minor,'_',letter)] *10
```

Comment: Though, if the columns already exist, why not just extract the column names *before* looping (eg, `cols = names(df)`), and loop on `cols`? Not clear from OP.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense but if the question was "I want to build the column names and do operations on them" you _can_ do that. It's probably not be the best way to do it though.

Comment: I really like the approach with `names(df)`. More easy then I thought.